# How to cast an `ArrayBuffer` to a `SharedArrayBuffer` in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arraybuffer, typed-arrays, sharedarraybuffer

Take the following snippet:

```
const arr = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]
const arrBuffer = (Float32Array.from(arr)).buffer
```

How would one cast this [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) to a [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer)?

```
const sharedArrBuffer = ...?
```

Comment: maybe slice can help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer/slice

Comment: @VadimHulevich how though? calling `slice` on an `ArrayBuffer` returns another `ArrayBuffer`, not a `SharedArrayBuffer`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that both `ArrayBuffer` and `SharedArrayBuffer` are backing data pointers that you only interact with through a typed array (like Float32Array, in your example). Array Buffers represent memory allocations and can't be "cast" (only represented with a typed array).

If you *have* one typed array already, and need to copy it into a new SharedArrayBuffer, you can do that with `set`:

```
// Create a shared float array big enough for 256 floats
let sharedFloats = new Float32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(1024));

// Copy floats from existing array into this buffer
// existingArray can be a typed array or plain javascript array
sharedFloats.set(existingArray, 0);
```

(In general, you can have a single array buffer and interact with it through multiple "typed lenses" - so, basically, casting an array buffer into different types, like Float32 and Uint8. But you can't cast an ArrayBuffer to a SharedArrayBuffer, you'll need to copy its contents.)